# in openlayer angular directive zoom buttons does not show

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, openlayers, openlayers-3, angular-openlayers

I don't have any zoom button in map

[image: i don't have any zoom button in map]

```
<openlayers ol-center="center" height="345px" width="560px">
    <ol-marker ol-marker-properties="coords"><ol-marker>
</openlayers>
```

how can i show them? plus and minus

i use angular openlayer directive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to import the css file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
```

Comment: The same problem in React + Material UI ... the same solution